# how can i make two arrays like each other in length?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

i have two arrays and want to make them same at the length and keys like this :

```
Array
(
    [1399-1-27] => 2
    [1399-1-26] => 6
    [1399-1-25] => 3
    [1399-1-24] => 3
    [1399-1-23] => 2
)
Array
(
    [1399-1-27] => 3.6666666666667
    [1399-1-26] => 4
    [1399-1-25] => 2.6666666666667
)
```

and what i want is the second array most convert to something like this :

```
Array
(
    [1399-1-27] => 3.6666666666667
    [1399-1-26] => 4
    [1399-1-25] => 2.6666666666667
    [1399-1-24] => 0
    [1399-1-23] => 0
)
```

does php have functions for this purpose or any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set the values of the first array to zero and then merge the two to achieve your result.

```
<?php

$array1= [
    '1399-1-27' => 2,
    '1399-1-26' => 6,
    '1399-1-25' => 3,
    '1399-1-24' => 3,
    '1399-1-23' => 2
];

$array2 = [
    '1399-1-27' => 3.6666666666667,
    '1399-1-26' => 4,
    '1399-1-25' => 2.6666666666667
];

$array1_0  = array_fill_keys(array_keys($array1), 0);
$result = array_merge($array1_0, $array2);
print_r($result);


?>
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [1399-1-27] => 3.6666666666667
    [1399-1-26] => 4
    [1399-1-25] => 2.6666666666667
    [1399-1-24] => 0
    [1399-1-23] => 0
)
```